# Unable to send mails using mailx command

Tags: linux, mailx

I tried sending an email using mailx as below:

```
    echo "something" | mailx -v -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
```

For this I got the below response
    "Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]".
I tried checking the log,but can't find it.Where could i see the log for this? How to resolve this?

Comment: I think your question would be better placed in either Server Fault, Unix & Linux or another Overflow. Stack Overflow is for programming related questions only.

Answer (score 3):

As a default, `mailx` try to use `localhost` (or `127.0.0.1`) as `smtp` server.

It seems that your local machine is not rumming an `smtp` daemon, so mailx cannot send any email.

You could:

1. Install, configure and manage an smtp daemon on your server. Imho, a very bad idea, if you are not an expert.
2. Check with your network (or ISP) administrators and discover the name of your local dedicated smtp server. You can pass needed parameters to `mailx` using `-S` option

   ```
   mailx -S smtp=smtp://you.smtp.server.example.com \
         -v -s "subject" recipient@somewhere.com
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file_containing_message_body | /bin/nail -S smtp=localhost:2525 \
-s Subject_stuff -r root@machine.somewhe.re <addressee@domain.tld>
```

works from script, in my case localhost:2525 is the entrance to an ssh-tunnel that leads to a working smtp port.